# Texturing: Adding black lines from geometry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, photorealism

First time posting on the Blender stackexchange!

My question is regarding the black outlines on this wall:

[image: reference image]

Basically I'm trying to recreate something similar to the image in cycles (different materials assigned to geometry) and I wonder what would be a good technique for that. What I do now is assign a different color material for each of the panels on the wall (basically every colorful panel is a face of the wall mesh). A few ideas I have:

- Adding additional loop cuts where the outline is and assigning a new black material to them.
- Modeling the outlines separately as a plane and adding using shrink-wrap to stick them to the wall.
- Using a mix shader and a mask with straight lines to determine where in each material the black line should be applied.

Basically my question boils down to: Can you somehow realistically blend between differerent materials on the same mesh, if they're right next to each other in cycles?

Any other ideas for this are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't think the cabinet doors have any outline actually, there is just some spacing between them and and it looks like an outline because of this high contrast image. I'd suggest try to model, colorize and lay them out seperatly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make a material with one section to handle the setting of the colors (I used a SeparateXYZ on the X followed by a ColorRamp), and then another section to make the "Trim" by using a Brick Texture with pure white fill-colors and a pure black mortar. Multiply the two together to copy the black from the trim onto the colors:

[image: Colors]

Comment: I really like the procedural setup for the panels, took some time to align the shader to my plane, but it worked out great! Thanks!